# SQL Calculate Jaccard Similarity (IoU)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 Postgres tables:

Table `UserItems`:

| uuid | user | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | item1 |
| 2 | 1 | item2 |
| 3 | 1 | item3 |
| 4 | 2 | item1 |
| 4 | 2 | item2 |
| 5 | 2 | item4 |
| 6 | 3 | item2 |
| 7 | 3 | item5 |
| 8 | 4 | item1 |
| 9 | 4 | item5 |

Table `Items`

| item | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | val_11 | val_12 | val_13 |
| item2 | val_21 | val_22 | val_23 |
| item3 | val_31 | val_32 | val_33 |
| item4 | val_41 | val_42 | val_43 |
| item4 | val_51 | val_52 | val_53 |

I'd like to calculate the Jaccard similarity given some input X. So for example, if the input X is `item1`, I'd like to find every user which has purchased `item1`, then calculate the Intersection Over Union (IOU) for every other item which any of those users have purchased. The output would then be:

| item | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | jaccard |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item2 | val_21 | val_22 | val_23 | 0.67 |
| item3 | val_31 | val_32 | val_33 | 0.33 |
| item4 | val_41 | val_42 | val_43 | 0.33 |
| item5 | val_51 | val_52 | val_53 | 0.33 |

My approach so far is

```
SELECT t1.item
FROM UserItems AS t1
JOIN Items AS t2 ON t1.item<>t1.item
WHERE t1.item={input}
GROUP BY t1.item
```

Then the idea was that I could count the total number of times that each item occurs divided by the total number of groups ... But I'm stumped on how to count the total number of times that each item occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way , if I didn't do any mistake :

```
select i.*, ii.jaccard 
from Items i
join ( 
  select item, count(distinct u.username) * 1.00 / uucount jaccard
  from userItems u
  join ( select tt.username, count(username) over () uucount 
         from userItems tt 
         where item = 'item1'
  ) t on t.username = u.username 
      and  u.item <> 'item1'
  group by u.item , t.uucount 
) ii on ii.item = i.item
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eed5926661682ea36bc550c48eca0a58)*

Comment: This solved it, thank you! can you explain how the lines `count(distinct u.username) * 1.00 / uucount jaccard` and `count(username) over () uucount` work? The first one, I don't understand where the variable `uucount` is coming from. And the second one, I'm just not familiar with the syntax. Apologies if these are basic questions, I'm very very new to SQL

Comment: uucount comes from  the qubquery, and `count(username) over () ` used to avoid another select to get the total counts